# Cannot call child component method using vue3 expose

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework

I try to call a method on a child component like described here
https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html#exposing-public-properties

Note, that I'm not using `<script setup>` and `defineExpose` here.

child-component

```
<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Checklist',
  setup(props, { expose }) {
  
    const validateForm = () => {
      let ok = true;
      console.log("validate");
      return ok;
    }

    expose({ validate: validateForm });
  }
})
</script>
```

parent

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Checklist ref="checklistElm" />
    <q-btn @click="save">Save</q-btn>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'ChecklistPage',
  components: {
    Checklist
  },
  setup() {
    const checklistElm = ref(null);
    return {
      save() {
        let ok = checklistElm.validate();
        /* or
        let ok = checklistElm.value.validate(); */      
      }
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Clicking on Save gives me

checklistElm.validate is not a function

or

checklistElm.value is null

as an error. Don't know why...

Although I'm using Quasar here this refers to a vue only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `.value` but you also forgot to return `checklistElm` from the setup function.  Without returning, it's not exposed to the template, so `ref="checklistElm"` is not actually working.

```js
return {
  checklistElm,
  save() {
    let ok = checklistElm.value.validate();
  }
}
```

This is a common mistake when using the `setup()` function. FYI, less boilerplate code and not having to remember to return things is why `<script setup>` is the recommended way of writing Composition API components.